# Node.js + LDAP - Create new user from Android

Tags: node.js, ldap

I am running LDAP server using node.js (ldapjs.org) and i want to create a new user from Android.

I created a user using the command 'ldapadd' and verified user creation was successful using the command "ldapsearch". These commands were directly run on the server.

What is the best way of creating the user from Android ? I assume i need to do a http post from Android and run another instance of node.js server (for http) which will accept the post request and run "ldapadd" on the machine's command line. Is this correct approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) from UnboundID to run an LDAP client on Android and interact with the LDAP Directory Server directly. See also [Neil's article](http://www.dirmgr.com/blog/2009/3/24/using-ldap-on-android.html).